# Resource attribute of DataWeave in Mule is not accepting flow variable

Tags: mule, classpath, esb, dataweave

My dataweave code configuration xml is as below :

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
    <dw:set-payload  resource="#[flowVars['sample']]" />
 </dw:transform-message>
```

where sample is a flow variable that contains the file path of the .dwl file that has the actual transformation logic.

```
<set-variable doc:name="Variable" value="file:D:/Transformer/sample.dwl" variableName="sample"/>
```

The error that i see when deploying the application is as follows:

```
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: FileNotFoundException: class path resource [#[flowVars['sample']]] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:197) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:324) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:345) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:163) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:268) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:83) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:275) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:150) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:104) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:170) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15) ~[tooling-support-3.7.3.jar:?]
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: IOException parsing XML document from URL [file:/C:/Users/Satyakeerthika_Ch/AnypointStudio/workspaceLatest/.mule/apps/sample/sample.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [#[flowVars['sample']]] cannot be opened because it does not exist (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:188) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
... 14 more
```

Can someone help me how to read the variable in the resource?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way, but you can use the MEL function to evaluate dataweave scripts inside a set-payload.

```
#[dw(<dw-script-string>)]
#[dw(<dw-script-string>, <out-content-type>)]
```

If you don't specify a content-type the default is java.

So, it would end up as:

```
<set-payload value="#[dw(<dw-script-string>)]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

[Link to docs](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/using-dataweave-in-studio#using-dataweave-language-elsewhere)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried using the dw() function as suggested by you. The value in the set payload i am using is as follows: 

 #[dw( payload map { First : $."First Name", number : $.Age, Last :$."Last Name", Date : $.DOB} , application/csv)]

But it is throwing some error while trying to save the xml. 

[Error:unknown class or illegal statement: org.mule.mvel2.ParserContext@2689a2]
[Near :{...dw(payload map {....}]
                       ^
[Line1 Column16]

Comment: It is working now. I have made the script as a string. Can i not add the input and output directives before the payload ? Because when i try to add it is throwing errors.

Comment: The error is:  Invalid input "0         %", expected versionMinor, wsnoeol or eol

Answer (score 0):

I also experience the same issue in my anypoint studio with Mule 3.9.0
I had to correct the java library in my anypoint studio using below guide.

1. right click on the project
2. select properties from the context menu
3. on the project propearties page select java build path
4. in java build path click on libraries
5. select Add Library -> click on JRE System Library
6. select alternate JRE and browse to the JDK you would like to add to the project

this should resolve your issue